# predict list of feature values in keras

Tags: numpy, keras

Am trying to use `predict_classes` in keras model, eventhough the input shape seems to be as required, the function throws exception

```
model = get_model()
flist = [10, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1]
X = np.array(flist)
print(X.shape) # prints (5,)
model.predict_classes(X)
```

it keeps throwing error

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_1_input to have shape (5,) but got array with shape (1,)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shape of X must be, `(Number_of_samples, input_dim)`. Use [`np.expand_dims`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.expand_dims.html).

```
X = np.expand_dims(X,axis=0)
```